# Why are json variables with "-" just displaying NaN in my table?

Tags: angular

Im trying to display the results from the json response from the server on my page, but some variables are displaying as NaN?

This is my json response from the server:

```
{"data":[{"id":"2","attributes":{"title":"Customer 1","status":"cancelled","end-date":"2019-01-01"}}]}
```

My customer service:

```
getCustomers(): Observable<Customer[]> {
        return this.http.get<Customer[]>(this.url);
    }
```

My customer component:

```
    getCustomers(): void {
        this.customerService.getCustomers()
          .subscribe(cs => {
              this.customers = cs;
              //console.log(this.customers);
          });
    }
```

My customer html:

```
        <tr *ngFor="let customer of customers.data">
            <td>{{ customer.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ customer.attributes.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ customer.attributes.status }}</td>
            <td>{{ customer.attributes.end-date }}</td>
        </tr>
```

This displays title and status but not end-date...? end-date returns NaN. Im guessing it is the "-" thats messing this up? How can I solve this?

Comment: Its probably evaluating it as a math expression `customer.attributes.end - date`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dashes are not allowed in Typescript/JavaScript identifiers, you will have to use array syntax to get the end date.

```
<td>{{ customer.attributes["end-date"] }}</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need handle the data first.

```
let date = new Date('2019-01-01');
```